# Changing the output of a theorem environment reference

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, labels

When referencing a theorem environment, you get an output consisting of *just* the number of the theorem. What I need is a theorem that, when referenced, displays the letter "T" next to the number (I'm using "T" as an example but I might want to use something else). Example:

> **Theorem 1.** In a Hausdorff space, every compact subspace is closed.
>
> T1 is important since, among other things, it's a crucial step on the proof that every continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff is a homeomorphism.

Here, T1 is the reference to Theorem 1.

How could I achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>One option is to define `\p@<cnt>` to hold `T` where `<cnt>` is the counter used by that theorem environment.</s>

LaTeX2e provides a `\labelformat{<cnt>}{<format>}` command which can be used to set a costumed reference format for counter `<cnt>`. In `<format>`, `#1` will be replaced by `\the<cnt>`, the normal counter representation.

See an example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\labelformat{theo}{T#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}\label{key}
  content
\end{theo}
\ref{key}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** If the theorem counter is shared with other theorem-like environment(s)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\newaliascnt{lemma}{theo}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lemma]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lemma}

\labelformat{theo}{T#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}\label{thm}
  content
\end{theo}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem}
  content
\end{lemma}

Theorem~\ref{thm} and Lemma~\ref{lem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\labelformat{theo}{T\thetheo}` (no @)

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\labelformat` is better, I'll adjust my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I discovered it by searching for `\csname p@` in the tex folder (base/latexrelease.sty).

Comment: This has the disadvantage that you cannot use `\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{Lemma}`, because also references to lemmas would be in the same format as for theorems.

Comment: @egreg True. A workaround using `\newaliascnt` from `aliascnt` package is added.

Answer (score 2):

The `cleveref` package allows such formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[theo]{Lemma}

\crefformat{theo}{#2T#1#3}
\crefformat{lem}{#2L#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}\label{test}
A lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{theo}\label{key}
  Content
\end{theo}

Consider \cref{key}, which has content. And \cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing a couple of bits: the most important is that `\newtheorem` should appear *after* loading `cleveref`; next I showed how to make the T in the link. I also added a lemma to see that the output is as expected with a suitable `\crefformat` declaration.

Comment: @egreg: Aha! That finally explains to me the docs for cleveref, section 8.2.1, saying that "The other two [#2 and #3] are used to mark the beginning and end of the part of the cross-reference that forms the hyperlink..."

Comment: @egreg: If one uses `thmtools`, then declarations of theorem-like environments can come *before* loading `cleveref`.

Comment: I consider that bad style nonetheless: first packages, then settings.